# Filter function throws error in data frame

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a data frame that includes factors. For one of the factor levels (etoh2), I'd like to count the number of occurrences of the word "never" and divide that by the total number (excluding na) to calc. a percentage.

The structure of the df looks like this:
[structure of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7FWZ.jpg)

And the levels of etoh2 look like this (using sapply):[etoh levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51H5.jpg)

Now, I try to filter using dplyr:

```
vipcls$etoh2 %>%
never <- count(filter(etoh2 == "never")
all <- count(etoh2)
ratio <- never/all
```

Which give me the following error message:[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0NZA.jpg)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let's figure this out.

You have your assignment operator in the wrong place for starts. The pipe %>% takes the output of one operation and makes it the first argument of the next. You are trying to do

```
vipcls$etoh2 %>%
  never # This is not a function
```

Here is the correct `dplyr` way.

```
vipcls %>%
  filter(etoh2 == "never") %>% # makes your filtered set
  count() # returns the number of records
```

To assign this, you put your assignment at the front:

```
never <- vipcls %>%
  filter(etoh2 == "never") %>% # makes your filtered set
  count() # returns the number of records
```

You can get `all` more simply:

```
all <- nrow(vipcls) #or
all <- count(vipcls)
```

Your code `count(etoh2)` will not work because `etoh2` is not its own object. It is part of the `vicpls` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, Ben has explained it better.

```
library(dplyr)

etoh1 <- c("Hello,", "how", "are", "you", "today", "!", "Hello,", "how", "are", "you", "today", "!")`enter code here`
etoh2 <- c("every day", "3-5/week", "1/week", "</1week", "<1/month", "never", "every day", "3-5/week", "1/week", "</1week", "<1/month", "never")

vipcls <- data.frame(cbind(etoh1, etoh2))
never <- count(vipcls %>% 
                 filter(etoh2 == "never"))
all <- nrow(vipcls) #assuming total rows = total etoh2
ratio <- never/all

ratio
```